# Benchmarked: lapply slower by more than an order of magnitude. Why?

Tags: r, lapply, benchmarking

I am worried that my code which makes liberal use of `lapply` (and `sapply`) might be slower by potentially more than an order of magnitude.

For example: take the following list, `ls`, which mirrors my data. It is small for illustrative purposes only, but trust me when chugging on millions of data points, `lapply` slows to a crawl.

```
set.seed(0)
dates <- as.character(seq.Date(as.Date('2023-01-01'), by = 'day', length.out = 365))
m <- sapply(dates, \(d) sample(1:10, 100, replace = TRUE))
rownames(m) <- seq(1001, 1100, 1)
ls <- list()
ls <- sapply(dates, \(d) {ls[[length(ls) + 1]] <- m[, d]; ls})
str(ls[1:3])
List of 3
 $ 2023-01-01: Named int [1:100] 9 4 7 1 2 7 2 3 1 5 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:100] "1001" "1002" "1003" "1004" ...
 $ 2023-01-02: Named int [1:100] 3 10 3 1 6 6 4 9 5 1 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:100] "1001" "1002" "1003" "1004" ...
 $ 2023-01-03: Named int [1:100] 1 10 4 9 9 9 9 6 6 4 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:100] "1001" "1002" "1003" "1004" ...
```

The goal is simple: calculate MAX(c(5 - x, 0)) for every element, x, in `ls` which number 36,500 data points. There are at least four different ways to do this, and they are benchmarked below.

```
library(bench)
bench::mark(a = {
              new <- sapply(dates, \(d) 
                        lapply(rownames(m), \(n) max(c(5 - ls[[d]][n], 0))))
              dimnames(new)[[1]] <- rownames(m)
              new |> lapply(sum) |> unlist() |> sum() # Checksum
              },
            b = {
              new <- sapply(ls, \(x) pmax(5 - x, 0))
              new |> lapply(sum) |> unlist() |> sum() # Checksum
            },
            c = {
              new <- do.call(cbind, ls)
              new <- pmax(5 - new, 0)
              new |> lapply(sum) |> unlist() |> sum() # Checksum
            },
            d = {
              new <- 5 - do.call(cbind, ls)
              new[new < 0] <- 0
              new |> lapply(sum) |> unlist() |> sum() # Checksum
            })
# A tibble: 4 × 13
  expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result memory     time      
  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list> <list>     <list>    
1 a           363.3ms  366.1ms      2.73    1.44MB     2.73     2     2      732ms <dbl>  <Rprofmem> <bench_tm>
2 b            26.1ms   32.2ms     26.5        2MB     9.48    14     5      527ms <dbl>  <Rprofmem> <bench_tm>
3 c            24.1ms   26.4ms     33.5     1.53MB     7.44    18     4      538ms <dbl>  <Rprofmem> <bench_tm>
4 d            23.7ms   26.3ms     21.0      1.6MB     5.25    12     3      572ms <dbl>  <Rprofmem> <bench_tm>
```

Why is there more than an order of magnitude difference between `a` and the rest? It is a simple enough calculation. Does this mean there are hidden pitfalls that one has to guard against when using `lapply`? And if so, what are they?

**EDIT**
After some constructive feedback from GuedesBF, I have cleaned up my code for the benchmarking which has sped things up, but the results are actually worse with nearly 2 orders of magnitude difference, yikes! Writing clear and efficient code is 90% of the battle with R and finding tutorials is hard which is why I am here. So thanks to all the contributors.

One thing is clear, the messy, nested `lapply` was part of the problem with the iterations being specified in the final function definition versus being cleanly specified up front like now.

```
bench::mark(a = {new <- sapply(ls, \(d)
                           lapply(d, \(x) max(c(5 - x, 0))))
                 new |> unlist() |> sum()}, # Checksum
            b = {new <- sapply(ls, \(x) pmax(5 - x, 0))
                 new |> unlist() |> sum()}, # Checksum
            c = {new <- do.call(cbind, ls)
                 new <- pmax(5 - new, 0)
                 new |> unlist() |> sum()}, # Checksum
            d = {new <- 5 - do.call(cbind, ls)
                 new[new < 0] <- 0
                 new |> unlist() |> sum()}) # Checksum
# A tibble: 4 × 13
  expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result memory     time      
  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list> <list>     <list>    
1 a           60.96ms   62.2ms      16.0    1.16MB     5.34     6     2      375ms <dbl>  <Rprofmem> <bench_tm>
2 b            7.64ms    8.3ms     118.     1.16MB     4.39    54     2      456ms <dbl>  <Rprofmem> <bench_tm>
3 c           621.7µs    818µs    1236.   715.93KB     7.17   517     3      418ms <dbl>  <Rprofmem> <bench_tm>
4 d           627.5µs  803.6µs    1218.   787.13KB     7.35   497     3      408ms <dbl>  <Rprofmem> <bench_tm>
```

Also, I was thinking what if the speed up is simply due to `pmax`, and there isn't a similar function available e.g. `mean`, `sqrt`, etc? Well, it appears that column binding instead of using `lapply` is always faster. Here are some benchmarking results using `sqrt` where there is still nearly 2 orders of magnitude difference.

```
bench::mark(a = {new <- sapply(ls, \(d)
                           lapply(d, \(x) sqrt(x)))
                 new |> unlist() |> sum()},
            b = {new <- do.call(cbind, ls)
                 new <- sqrt(new)
                 new |> unlist() |> sum()})
# A tibble: 2 × 13
  expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result memory     time      
  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list> <list>     <list>    
1 a            32.6ms   35.6ms      28.0    1.15MB     5.09    11     2      393ms <dbl>  <Rprofmem> <bench_tm>
2 b           475.9µs    570µs    1713.   430.73KB     6.82   754     3      440ms <dbl>  <Rprofmem> <bench_tm>
```

Comment: You are using lapply everywhere, so clearly just the use of lapply is not the problem. A first thing I can identify is that in `a`, you are actually using nested loops (as in `lapply(x, \(y) lapply(y, \(z))` which can get very slow. You might end up doing element-wise operations, instead of vectorizing the functions over longer list elements

Comment: In `sapply(dates, \(d) lapply(rownames(m) ....`, we have at least `length(rownames(m)) * length(dates)` iterations, or 365,000 in the given example.

Comment: Some additional minor advice:
`new |> lapply(sum) |> unlist() |> sum()` looks kind of redundant and innefficient. If we are eventually going to `unlist` and `sum`, `new |> unlist() |> sum()` should get us the same result. Even `sum(new)` outputs the same here. Note that `sum` works on vectors or matrices, and `new` is already a matrix, so we do not need to unlist it.

Comment: I confess I am not the most fluent in R. Much of my code writing is focused on working through the error messages versus just spitting out code. `sum(new)` returns an error for `a` which is why I unlisted it then use the same code in the other steps for apples to apples comparison. But, you are right, `new |> unlist() |> sum` gives the same result for `a` making `lapply` redundant. As for using lapply everywhere, that is only so the benchmark will run for every case. If you look really closely, `new` is not identical for every case. And I don't really understand the difference tbh.

Comment: My "using lapply everywhere" statement is irrelevant. See if you understand the issue with the nested loops, which is the most valuable observation here. The main issue with `a` is `sapply(d, \(d) lapply(d, \(x) ...`

Comment: That's a lot of piping going on as well.  What happens if you just nest the functions?

Comment: And definitely use `utils::Rprof` to see what's going on.